# Job offers world map

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, jobs, feedback

Maybe it was already asked, but a world map would be nice for careers. Where you can see countries with jobs. Then you can zoom or filter by technology and so.

 Like the candidate search for employers but in reverse.

Comment: How does this help users more effectively navigate through Careers?

Comment: Like if I want to see the  jobs in my preferred segment of the world, I just take glance of the map and I know everything.

Comment: But... how does that help you find a job? You would know how many jobs there are in your area, but that's not very helpful...

Comment: In my region there is not too many. And not just the number but the types/links to the offer. A new search view. I'm not a power user but I wasn't able to filter on different countries at once in the location filter. (which could be my bad)

Comment: That is an interesting point, in some areas (im thinking the european union) where there are next to no work restrictions several contries might make sense if you live near the border

Comment: I could be also good for people looking to move. Maybe filter by jobs offering relocation/telecommute...

Comment: I would actually really appreciate something like that. Especially when my target area would usually be "Europe". Perhaps with some additional filtering to not just show everything. Would be more ideal to me than the current radius.

Comment: I would have found this interesting at a point in life where telecommuting was beginning to seem untenable, and I was left thinking "*Where do I want to go?*" Not sure how much this would 'cost', but it would be rather nifty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're in the middle of redesigning a few pages on Careers.  While the map is not a focus, we are looking to bring in a geographical element to the front page which should cover your use case.  We'll have some early versions to show off in a few weeks.

Comment: In about 6 to 8 weeks

Comment: Hope it's gonna be good :)

Comment: Wouldn't this be a `status-planned` or `status-deferred` then rather than declined?

Comment: Waiting to see the changes... :D